# Sheets Script: Why did my script stop working?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, onsubmit

My Google Apps Script has stopped working. The process of the script is:

1. A Google Form is submitted
2. Data is filled into a Sheet
3. This triggers the script
4. The script writes a value to a specific cell in the new row.

Everything works except for the script. It no longer writes the script value. **Was there a breaking change that would have caused this?**
The intent is to create a custom ID within column "I" that begins with "BP" followed by the next available number.

```
function onSubmit(e) {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet()
 var row = e.range.getRow()
 sheet.getRange(row, 9).setValue("BP" + Number(14069 + row))
}
```

Comment: [getActiveSheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivesheet) might be the reason why as it tried to get the currently active sheet and you might submit the form without even accessing the Spredsheet. Could you please try to change it to [getSheetByName](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename) and see if that makes any difference?

Answer (score 0):

[Mateo Randwolf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12835757/mateo-randwolf)'s answer:

---

[`getActiveSheet`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivesheet) might be the reason why as it tried to get the currently active sheet and you might submit the form without even accessing the Spreadsheet. Could you please try to change it to [`getSheetByName`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename) and see if that makes any difference?